# Is this function Lipschitzian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $h :S^1=\{x\in\mathbb R^d: \left \| x \right \|_2=1\} \to  \mathbb R^+ $ be a Lipschitz function.

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded open set and
>   \begin{align}
> \Psi:B\setminus\{0\}\quad&\to\quad\Omega\setminus\{0\}\\[1ex]
> y\quad&\mapsto\quad y\cdot h\left(\frac y{\|y\|}\right).
> \end{align}

My question is:
Is  $\Psi$ a Lipschitz function?

Comment: $S_1$ contains all points of unit norm. Is $y /in S_1$?

Comment: @Bey : $y$ is in $B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}=\{y\in \mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\}: \left \| y \right \|_2<1\}$, so $\frac{y}{\left \| y \right \|_2}\in S^1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be an upper bound for $h$ and $L$ be its Lipschitz constant. Then,
\begin{align*}
\|\psi(x) - \psi(y)\|
&\le \|x-y\| h(\frac x{\|x\|}) + \|y\| \, \Big\| h(\frac x {\|x\|}) - h(\frac y{\|y\|}) \Big\|
\\&\le C \|x-y\| + \| y \| \, L \, \Big| \frac x{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\Big|
\\&\le C \|x-y\| + L \, \Big| \frac {x\|y\|}{\|x\|} - y\Big|
\\&\le C \|x-y\| + L \, \|x-y\| + L \, \Big| \frac {x\|y\|}{\|x\|} - x\Big|
\\&\le C \|x-y\| + L \, \|x-y\| + L \, | \|x\| - \|y\| |
\\&\le C \|x-y\| + 2 \, L \, \|x-y\|.
\end{align*}